# RailsAdmin: polymorphic type as custom filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphism, rails-admin

Given this model,

```
class Flat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
end
```

In RailsAdmin, I would like to add a owner_type filter. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like for all association fields, filtering is turned off by default. All you need to do is turn it back on.

```
class Flat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true

  rails_admin do
    list do
      filters [:owner_type] # if you'd like an owner_type filter by default
      field :owner_type do
        filterable true # allow owner_type to be filtered on
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It hides all other fields (which are filterable by default), but it solves my problem, thank you!

Comment: Ah yes! You'll just need to add the fields that you want to be able to edit for the object: `field :field1`, `field :field2`, etc. Or use: `include_fields :field1, :field2`.